# Django - Why user did not pass IsAdminUser, but django does not throw exception of unauth?

Tags: python, django

Here is my sample code of using Token Authen:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
class test_api(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated)
    def get(self,request):
        return HttpResponse("You call random test api")
```

I am using Token Authen, with my header of request like this, this is a Token of NOT AdminUser

```
 Authorization : Token fc823d7a1d8973056e11e9c8b974f17e351c4263
```

When I call the api, It print out of terminal these lines

```
False
[23/Aug/2021 10:39:20] "GET /user/get-user HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

I suppose the `False` got print out from `IsAdminUser` permission. However, the code still reponse 200 and give me response of `You call random test api`.

Only when I give the wrong Token, I receive 403 Unauth response.

FYI my user model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),  **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """Creata and saves a new super user"""
        user = self.create_user(email,password)
        user.is_staff = False
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that support using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: Can you add the `IsAdminUser` and `IsAuthenticated` classes?

Comment: Are you sure that you were using the `HttpResponse`? from where is it gets imported? Shouldn't it be `Response`?

Comment: @JPG `HttpResponse` works fine, and I been using it for many times. So I think it should not be a problem

Comment: @JPG  IsAdminUser, and IsAuthenticated is built-in, I import from rest_framework.permission. Already included in the post

Comment: @Chau when you said "_a Token of NOT AdminUser_", do you mean the user is not a "superuser"? Or do you mean the user is not a "staff" user?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano has no role, only being active (default). Already included my model into the post

Comment: Where did you print `False`?

Comment: @bdbd there is no `print`

Comment: Could you add a print of `print("user.is_staff", user.is_staff)` within `get()` before you return the `HttpResponse`? Maybe it is `True`?

Comment: Sorry to @NielGodfreyPonciano after checking database this user is tick true for `is_staff`. and `IsAdminUser` is applied on `is_staff` column. Sorry for troublesome. I will close this post. Thanks @bdbd for efforts

Comment: If you add your response on `is_staff` problem to answer. I will upvote and accept your answer if you want @NielGodfreyPonciano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser):

> The `IsAdminUser` permission class will deny permission to any user, unless `user.is_staff` is `True` in which case permission will be allowed.

Thus, it seems that the user for the token has `is_staff` set to `True`. You can confirm this by adding the following lines in your `get()`

```
def get(self, request):
    print("request.user.is_staff", request.user.is_staff)
    return HttpResponse("You call random test api")
```